# foreach "Invalid argument supplied" when supplying array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am getting a `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` warning that I have no explanation for.

Everything works as expected, however it seems that `foreach()` does not like an array as argument even if the array contains another array (so valid for `foreach()`)?

I have the following code:

```
foreach ( $distr_continents[$continent_id] as $distributor_data )
{
    echo('<td>' . $distributor_data . '</td>');
}
```

The `$distr_continents[$continent_id]` looks like this:

```
 Array
 (
  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [1] => <td valign="top"></td>
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [1] => <td valign="top"></td>
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [1] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [2] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [3] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [4] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [5] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [6] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [7] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [8] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [9] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [10] => <td valign="top"></td>
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [1] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [2] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [3] => <td valign="top"></td>
        [4] => <td valign="top"></td>
    )

 )
```

What am I missing here??

Comment: are you going to echo this, why not just wrap/concatenate it with table rows, and implode/glue those sub arrays

Comment: I think the foreach should be find, but your print statement not since you try to convert an array to string

Comment: @Ghost - no, `echo` used only for debug purposes

Comment: @Rizier123 - the `foreach` isn't fine since it yields a warning

Comment: you are using echo on array $distrubutor_data

Comment: Before the loop, try print_r ($distr_continents[$continent_id]);  are you _sure_ that the you're feeding an array into the loop?

Comment: Others have raised good points. What is the exact error message?  Often paraphrasing error messages loses their actual meaning - and double check the line numbers

Comment: @Arunas - the point is just the warning... it's not about displays, that's not the point here as the code is simplified here..... point is that `$distr_continents[$continent_id]` is not a valid `foreach()` argument for some reason that I don't understand...

Comment: can you show here how you created this array ?

Comment: @RaheelKhan - does not matter how it's created, you see the var dump above to see the structure

Comment: @Michal, are you saying that your code otherwise works and produces the result, just that there's a warning?

Comment: @Arunas - yes exactly.... all is fine, it works, just produces `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`... where `$distr_continents[$continent_id]` obviously IS an array as you see in the structure above....

Comment: @Michal - Php won't lie to you.  So I really do recommend printing out the array immediately before the loop using print_r.  Make sure that it really is what you think it is.  Keep in mind that if you display code on SO that is not the actual code that you're testing, chances are we cant help!

Comment: @Arunas - I am not here since yesterday... you see what it is above... it's a `print_r` just before the foreach....

Comment: I have a feeling that this is may be because of html tags. As when i try to run your code the html part is getting rendered. Thats why may be the foreach construct is not getting correctly executed. PS Its just a thought.

Comment: @RaheelKhan - it is getting rendered, again, that's not the point... the array produces a warning with the foreach....

Comment: @Michal - And just to be certain, you've checked the line number for the 'foreach' warning?  Because I've populated an array with your data and run the php code and set error reporting to E_ALL, and there's no warning.  So either the warning is from someplace completely different, or there's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might fix your warning.

```
foreach ( (array) $distr_continents[$continent_id] as $distributor_data )
{
    echo('<td>' . $distributor_data . '</td>');
}
```

Comment: yea, actually solved it, haven't thought of that, thanx

Comment: This can be a bug as i have read few articles about it, and also the warning occurs when the array does not turn to be a valid array. Its just what i've read.

Comment: Wow.  Well, this does mean that there's something special about how you're populating the data, which is why it's important to actually post a bit of code that _actually_ produces the error condition

Answer (score 0):

I think the array is multidimensional so you need to run a loop inside also...This is just a reference

hope you are understanding it.

```
foreach ( $distr_continents[$continent_id] as $distributor_data )
{
      foreach($distributor_data as $d_data){
          echo('<td>' . $d_data . '</td>');
      }
}
```

Comment: please read the question - missing the point - $distr_continents[$continent_id] yields "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" - question is WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $distr_continents[$continent_id] is always an array.

Just encapsulate foreach loop as below.

```
if(isset($distr_continents[$continent_id]) && is_array($distr_continents[$continent_id])){

   // Your foreach loop here

}
```

Also you are trying to echo an array. This is wrong and will throw a warning.

Comment: please read the question - missing the point - $distr_continents[$continent_id] yields "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" - question is WHY?

Comment: It is because somehow it is not an array I think. I don't think there will be any other problem.